# Read Exif data from picture of MediaLibrary in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, exif, media-library, camera-roll

Code:

```
MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;

foreach (var picture in pictures)
{                                
    // get Exif data here
}
```

How can i get the Exif property for the picture orientation for a specific picture from MediaLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the file's contents as a `Stream` then you can use my [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library. It'll give you all sorts of metadata about images in many file formats.

Comment: i have indeed access to the file as a Stream with "picture.GetImage();". But how to use the stream with your library? Didn't find any documentation about that on the project site...

Comment: If you have a `System.IO.Stream` you pass it to `ImageMetadataReader.Read(stream)` and receive back a set of directory objects, each containing tagged metadata values.